# How to create a DataFrame from a RDD where each row is a dictionary?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a rdd that has dictionaries for each row and I am trying to figure out how to convert it to a dataframe in PySpark.

If I use `.toDF()`, my columns are wrong since the dictionaries can vary. Is there a way to work around it?

```
 {'user': 'A',
  'rows': 214,
  'date': '2018-12-18',
  'date_x': '2018-12-18',
  'error': 'None',}
 {'user': 'B',
  'rows': 1416,
  'date': '2015-09-03',
  'error': 'None',
  'pollen': 't'}]
```

I am looking to create dataframe which has a union of all the keys in both of these dictionaries (null appears in the rows where we don't have the value for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the **`dict`** by using **`.json`** method in spark.

Then spark `infers the schema` and keeps `null` values for the rows which won't have values for in it.

***Example*:**

```
data=[{'user': 'A',
  'rows': 214,
  'date': '2018-12-18',
  'date_x': '2018-12-18',
  'error': 'None'},
 {'user': 'B',
  'rows': 1416,
  'date': '2015-09-03',
  'error': 'None',
  'pollen': 't'}]

spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)).show()
```

***Result:***

```
+----------+----------+-----+------+----+----+
|      date|    date_x|error|pollen|rows|user|
+----------+----------+-----+------+----+----+
|2018-12-18|2018-12-18| None|  null| 214|   A|
|2015-09-03|      null| None|     t|1416|   B|
+----------+----------+-----+------+----+----+
```

**`To check Schema:`**

```
spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)).printSchema()
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- error: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pollen: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rows: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but since it's a rdd, it cannot loop through the data and use the .read method. I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: @Rob, when we do **`spark.sparkContext.parallelize(<rdd>)`** then we can use **`spark.read.json`** can read the parallelized rdd in json format.